# Submitting Data from tokeninput.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I have recently set up https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput on one of my web sites.

I am trying to allow the users of the sites to create a list from a number of options that I give them.. Once the user is done selecting all their items and click submit I get no values back.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong..

**HTML**

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="demo-input" name="name" />
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo-input").tokenInput("json.php");
  });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$name =$_POST["name"]);
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)?

Comment: I did not understand the documentation when it came to submitting.. I saw how to set it up (and I got that working)

Comment: So I don't understand what's is the problem: it's works or not?

Comment: Autocomplete js adds value to the text field, however when I click on the submit button under the post value the field value is blank.

Comment: Have you declared the `<form>` in the HTML?

Comment: yes, all the other fields work fine..

Comment: The problem is that the `<input>` is empty before sending the form or that you can't retry the value in php script?

Comment: I see.. The input itself is empty.. even do I see the names selected on the list .. I am not populating a hidden field to pass the values..

Comment: Try to change `#demo-input` with another id. The function have some parameters with no-result as demo (see documentation: noResultsText etc.), maybe there are linked to `#demo-input` (obviously you have to change also in the js function)

Comment: I am using the onAdd: function to populate a hidden field with all the ID's that I need to save to the database..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing so far to get around the issue..

As the user adds and removes items from the list I am using the onAdd and onDelete functions to add the id's to a hidden field .. Once all the ID's are populated I can use the standard $_post[] command in php to read the values

here is a sample of the code for anyone else who might have the same issue

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="list_of_items" name="list_of_items" />
    <input type="hidden" id="list_of_items_by_id" name="list_of_items_by_id" />    
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var field_value = $("#list_of_items_by_id").val();

    $("#list_of_items").tokenInput("json.php",{
        hintText: "Start typing the name of the item", 
        tokenValue:"item_id",

        onAdd: function (item) {        
            var field_value = $('#list_of_items_by_id').val();
            if (field_value != ""){
                $('#list_of_items_by_id').val(field_value+","+ item.item_id);
            }else{
                $('#list_of_items_by_id').val(item.user_id);
            }               

        },

        onDelete: function (item) {
            var field_value = $('#list_of_items_by_id').val().replace(',,',',').replace(item.user_id,'');
            $('#list_of_items_by_id').val(field_value); 
        }       

    });         
});
```